# How to make the content smaller to connect with the footer?

Tags: php, html, footer

I have a big empty space between the [website](http://classicitalianbikes.com/wp/) content and the footer, can someone help me to get this space out and make the content connect the footer?

Comment: Posting `image` and `source code` would have stopped me from posting this comment.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You have few empty paragraph under `.wonderplugincarousel-container` and big margin-bottom in few divs

Comment: Yes I saw that, do you have any idea how to delete those paragraphs with CSS? Tried to find on the puglin but cant find where the <p> are to delete it

Comment: Try this `.wonderplugincarousel-container ~ p {display: none;}`